# Fuseki server on Mac - 404 in localhost:3030

Tags: http-status-code-404, sparql, jena, fuseki

1. I dowloaded the Fuseki stand alone server from here: http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/#download-fuseki
2. chose the executable jar
3. configured a file:

   ```
   @prefix :        <#> .
   @prefix fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
   @prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

   @prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
   @prefix tdb:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
   @prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .

   [] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;
      fuseki:services (
        <#testService>
      ) .

   <#testService>
     rdf:type                        fuseki:Service ;
     fuseki:name                     "testService" ;
     fuseki:serviceQuery             "query" ;
     fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore    "get" ;
     fuseki:dataset                   <#Dataset> .

   <#Dataset>
     rdf:type ja:RDFDataset ;
     rdfs:label "a label for your dataset" ;
     ja:defaultGraph 
       [ rdfs:label "sample.rdf" ;
         a          ja:MemoryModel ;
         ja:content [ja:externalContent <file:/Users/hdeus/Documents/KnowledgeBase/SPARQL/TestData/sample.rdf> ] .
       ] .
   ```
4. Ran  `java -jar fuseki-server.jar --config=fuseki_config.ttl`

   ```
   20:46:08 INFO  Home Directory: /Users/hdeus/Documents/KnowledgeBase/SPARQL/Engines/.
   20:46:08 WARN  No such directory for static content: /Users/hdeus/Documents/KnowledgeBase/SPARQL/Engines/.
   20:46:08 WARN  You may need to set the --pages or --home option to configure static content correctly
   20:46:08 INFO  Configuration file: fuseki_config.ttl
   20:46:08 INFO  Service: <file:///Users/hdeus/Documents/KnowledgeBase/SPARQL/Engines/fuseki_config.ttl#testService>
   20:46:08 INFO    name = testService
   20:46:08 INFO    query = /testService/query
   20:46:08 INFO    graphStore(R) = /testService/get
   20:46:09 WARN  Already initialized: dataset = testService
   20:46:09 INFO  Dataset path = /testService
   20:46:09 INFO  Fuseki 0.2.8-SNAPSHOT 20130530-0913
   20:46:09 INFO  Started 2013/06/01 20:46:09 EDT on port 3030
   ```
5. Went to `http://localhost:3030/` And got the following message:

   > Error 404: Not Found
   >   Fuseki - version 0.2.8-SNAPSHOT (Build date: 20130530-0913)

What I am doing wrong? From various sources, this is working for others but not for me.

Comment: Some of the warning output says "No such directory for static content: /Users/hdeus/Documents/KnowledgeBase/SPARQL/Engines/".  Does that directory exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you by any chance either copy/move the Fuseki JAR from the original location you downloaded it to on your machine?

As the warning messages in the log output state Fuseki was unable to find the directory for static content, it expects to find a `/pages` directory under the directory in which you launch it.  This directory should be present in your download whether you downloaded the source/binaries.

This warning does not mean that Fuseki is not running just that you won't have the UI available to you, if you are a beginner then you likely want the UI available.  The fix is to make sure you copy over the `/pages` directory from your download or to use the `--pages` flag to point to the location from your download.

If you make a SPARQL query to the endpoint URI like `http://localhost:3030/testService/query` then you will be able to get a result.  Note that `testService` is the value from the `fuseki:name` property in your config file.